# Distinct with the list of my class

Tags: c#, list

I have a class:

```
private class Part
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Part part = obj as Part;

        return this.Id == part.Id;
    }
}
```

Also I have a List of this class, so I need to use distinct on this list. Thats what I do:

```
List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();
//adding items
parts = parts.Distinct().ToList();
```

But nothing happens. Can anybody tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When overriding `Equals` you have to override `GetHashCode` as well:

```
private class Part
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }

    // Whenever overiding Equals
    // You have to override this method too
    public override int GetHashCode() {
      return String.IsNullOrEmpty(Id) ? 0 : Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Part part = obj as Part;

        // if obj is not of Part you should return false
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, part))
          return false; 

        return this.Id == part.Id;
    }
}
```

The very *reason of the misbehaviour* is that `Distinct` ***first tests*** `GetHashCode` and ***only then*** `Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

To perform `Distinct` operation on your class you need to supply Comparer implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>`

**Example:**

```
public class SelectedItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Part>
{

    public new bool Equals(Part x, Part y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Part source)
    {
        string code = source.Id.ToString();

        return code.GetHashCode();

    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();
//adding items
parts = parts.Distinct(new SelectedItemComparer()).ToList();
```

Reference: [Distinctly LINQ – Getting a Distinct List of Objects](http://geekswithblogs.net/dtotzke/archive/2010/12/06/143021.aspx)